# Can't open synaptic package manager after installing get deb

Tags: package-management

I have install getdeb by following command

```
echo "Downloading GetDeb and PlayDeb" &&
wget http://archive.getdeb.net/install_deb/getdeb-repository_0.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb http://archive.getdeb.net/install_deb/playdeb_0.3-1~getdeb1_all.deb &&

echo "Installing GetDeb" &&
sudo dpkg -i getdeb-repository_0.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb &&

echo "Installing PlayDeb" &&
sudo dpkg -i playdeb_0.3-1~getdeb1_all.deb &&

echo "Deleting Downloads" &&
rm -f getdeb-repository_0.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb &&
rm -f playdeb_0.3-1~getdeb1_all.deb
```

now when i open synaptic package manger i get following error and it is not opening

```
E: The value 'trusty-getdeb' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

what should i do? please help!!

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Please add the output of the command `grep trusty /etc/apt/sources.list*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it using this:

```
gksudo gedit /root/.synaptic/synaptic.conf
```

searched for 'trusty'  and replaced it with Your Ubuntu codename.

You can get your ubuntu codename by running command:

```
lsb_release -sc
```

Once you've done then run the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now synaptic must run again.

Source: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/synaptic/+question/213406

Comment: yeah this fix my problem synaptic is running properly

Comment: @coderklane that's good then mark it as answer, please take a look http://askubuntu.com/tour